# Как правильно сделать шапку во flex?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Здравствуйте.
Помогите, пожалуйста, правильно сделать шапку d.
Хочу посмотреть пример, так как только начал изучать flexbox, если это не запрещено правилами сайта, то, пожалуйста, помогите)
Образец шапки тут: shveypokrov.ru

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}
html {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: #B63D32;
}
body {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: #B63D32;
}
#page-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.main_header {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 flex-direction: row;
 height: 25%;
 width: 100%;
 position: relative;
 border: 3px solid black; 
}
header {
 display: flex;
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 border: 3px solid red;
}
.container1 {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 width: 100%;
 height: 25% 
}
.logo {
 width: 185px;
 height: 250px;
}
.logo img {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
}
.main_title {
 
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: flex-end;
}
.subtitle {
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}
.second_subtitle {
 
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: flex-start;
}
nav {
 display: flex;
}
nav .top_navigation {
 display: flex;
}
.top_navigation ul {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 justify-content: space-arround;
 align-items: center;
}
.top_navigation li {
 margin-left: 100px; 
}
.top_navigation a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
 <title>ШвейПокров</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="page-wrapper">
  <div class="main_header">
   <header>
     <div class="container1">
      <div class="logo">
       <img src="img/logo.png" alt="ШвейПокров"> 
      </div>
      <div class="main_title">
       "ШвейПокров"
      </div>
      <div class="subtitle">
        Православная швейная мастерская
      </div>
      <div class="second_subtitle">
       доставка по всей России
      </div>
      <nav class="top_navigation">
       <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">О нас</a></li>
       </ul>
      </nav>
     </div>
    </header>
  </div> 
   <section>
    <div class="container2">
     
    </div>
   </section>
   <footer>
   <div class="container3">
    
   </div>    
   </footer>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Для начала стоило бы основы html , css поучить,css файл:почему бы не объединить элементы html,body? Левый блок просто падает при переходе на др страницу.

Comment: Хочу посоветовать отличный сайт с подробной информацией про все правила `flexbox`: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Вплане, выпалает? То, что оно position: fixed? Это задумка такая))

Comment: Ошибка в `justify-content: space-arround;` две r, вот и не позиционируется, а вы боритесь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот пример:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ul{
 list-style: none;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: #B63D32;
}

#page-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}

.main_header {
  width: 100%;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

.logo{
  width: 130px;
}

.main_title, .container1{
  text-align: center;
}

.top_navigation ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.top_navigation a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="page-wrapper">
    <header class="main_header">
      <div class="container1">
        <img src="http://shveypokrov.ru/img/logo.png" alt="ШвейПокров" class="logo">
        <div class="main_title">
          "ШвейПокров"<br>
          Православная швейная мастерская<br>
          доставка по всей России
        </div>
        <nav class="top_navigation">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">О нас</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Может это не совсем по правилам этого сайта, но я рискну ответить.
Посмотрел сайт, он во многих местах состоит из ошибок и не будет выглядеть нормально без переработки. К сожалению, многие воспринимают верстку как нечто такое простое, чему даже учиться не нужно.
Ответ, который решит этот вопрос такой - нужен верстальщик. Или вам нужно пройти обучение - самообразование или курсы - вам решать, но невозможно сверстать сайт не зная базы.

Какие флексбоксы?! Это еще очень рано.
Взглянув на левую колонку, думаю, что стоит начать с темы позиционирования.
Извините, если это не то, что вы ожидали, но ответ таков.

Comment: За этим сюда и приходят, что бы научиться!

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, какие я допустил ошибки в HTML и CSS и я поставлю Вам галочку

Comment: @Quick Brown Fox вы крайне страшно добавили сайдбар слева. Сайдбары обычно добавляют флексбоксами либо 2 более старых варианта. Если бы мы были где-то в 2014 вы бы должны были сделать его через `float: left` (я и сейчас так делаю). Менее популярный вариант будет сделать через `inline-block`.

Comment: @Telion спасибо, а помимо прочего, есть ли какие-либо ошибки? Хочется знать, где я сглупил-ступил, чтобы сделать работу над ошибками)

Comment: @MaxWall мне посоветовали flexbox тут же изучать недавно. Но скорее всего они не знали, что я в вёрстке сайтов всего лишь десять-пятнадцать дней :))

Comment: @Quick Brown Fox у вас полно ошибок начинающего верстальщика. Я бы на вашем месте серьезно бы нашел пару статей в сети про верстку сайтов и изучил бы их подробно. Могу посоветовать Хабрахабр(https://habrahabr.ru/post/202408/) для этого. После чего вы уже сами поймете и захотите полностью переписать сей сайт. А с вопросами из обучающих статей обращайтесь сюда.